# Clicking next button with Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the macro to open a page in Internet Explorer, enter login information, click login, then on the next page, click 'I agree'.

```vb
Sub Test1()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "website.com"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set idoc = IE.document
    
    idoc.all.orgCode.Value = "****"
    idoc.all.UserName.Value = "****"
    idoc.all.Password.Value = "****"
    
    Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
    Dim eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    
    For Each ele In eles
        If ele.Value = "Login" Then
            ele.Click
        Else
        End If
    Next ele
End Sub
```

This gets me to the page where I need to click 'I agree'. How do I click the 'I agree' button?

Here is what comes up under inspect element
[image]

Comment: Chances are this won't be easy to do with the website you're trying. There are better tools out there for conducting such things and websites aren't typically fans of automated logins.

Comment: @pgSystemTester what would be easier? after i hit that button i need to do data entry from an excel sheet. I already got past the login page.

Comment: @aims97 Your code does not seems to have any attempt on clicking "I agree" so what is your problem here? Have you tried to get element with something like `idoc.getElementByID("action")`?

Comment: @RaymondWu i am new to all of this, i actually just figured it out myself. Thank you! I do have another question though if you are able to help.

Comment: @aims97 Since you have resolved it, you can submit your own answer (and accept it later on). Please ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Next ele
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Set eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("input")

```
    For Each ele In eles
    If ele.Value = "I Agree" Then
        ele.Click
    Else
    End If
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).